# Comparing URL parameter to Property in Filtered Array. - Nextjs/Javascritp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filter, next.js

I am using Nextjs/Javascript. I am trying to filter the name property in each object (that is inside an array) based on whether the comparison function comes back true or not. However I am not sure if I am going about it correctly. I am using the localcomapre function. Below are my code snippets.

Below is my comparison hook.

```
export default function useLocalCompare(s1, s2) {
  s1
  s2

  if (s1.localeCompare(s2, undefined, { sensitivity: "base" }) === 0) {
    console.log("Both supplied parameters are the same");

    return "True";
  } else {
    return "False";
  }
}
```

And The filter function looks like

```
const filtteredarray = flatarrayofvalues.filter(
         useLocalCompare(placeholder.name, genre)
      );
```

Am I doing this right? I only want it to filter out the object where the name property matches the genre value after both have gone through my useLocalCompare function.

Value of filtteredarray below

```
[{ id: 28, name: 'Action' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Adventure' },
  { id: 16, name: 'Animation' },
  { id: 35, name: 'Comedy' },
  { id: 80, name: 'Crime' },
  { id: 99, name: 'Documentary' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Drama' },
  { id: 10751, name: 'Family' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Fantasy' },
  { id: 36, name: 'History' },
  { id: 27, name: 'Horror' },
  { id: 10402, name: 'Music' },
  { id: 9648, name: 'Mystery' },
  { id: 10749, name: 'Romance' },
  { id: 878, name: 'Science Fiction' },
  { id: 10770, name: 'TV Movie' },
  { id: 53, name: 'Thriller' },
  { id: 10752, name: 'War' },
  { id: 37, name: 'Western' },
  { name: 'Trending' },
  { name: 'Top Rated' }
]
```

The genre value comes from the URL. It something like localhost/genre. I pull the genre down and then want to compare it to the name value of each object in the array displayed above. Where am I going wrong?

The piece of code below works without issue, but the problem is I am hardcoding the genre name, it snot being pulled down from the URL. Also, I don't have it going through my useLocalCompare function described above.

```
(flatarrayofvalues !== null && genre !== null) {
      const filtteredarray = flatarrayofvalues.filter(
        (placeholder) => placeholder.name == "Horror")
```

However the problem is I am hardcoding the genre name, it snot being pulled down from the URL. Also, I don't have it going through my useLocalCompare function described above.

So I know the overall structure of code code is correct along with the theory of what I am trying to do, but I am unsure of exactly where I am going wrong when trying to introduce the useLocalCompare function and the genre variable.

Note, when I simply console.log my genre, it pulls down my URL Params correctly. So I know the problem is not with what is contained inside the genre variable.

Answer (score 0):

If I get the goal right... I just slightly edited your code:

```js
const data = [{ id: 28, name: 'Action' },{ id: 12, name: 'Adventure' },{ id: 16, name: 'Animation' },{ id: 35, name: 'Comedy' },{ id: 80, name: 'Crime' },{ id: 99, name: 'Documentary' },{ id: 18, name: 'Drama' },{ id: 10751, name: 'Family' },{ id: 14, name: 'Fantasy' },{ id: 36, name: 'History' },{ id: 27, name: 'Horror' },{ id: 10402, name: 'Music' },{ id: 9648, name: 'Mystery' },{ id: 10749, name: 'Romance' },{ id: 878, name: 'Science Fiction' },{ id: 10770, name: 'TV Movie' },{ id: 53, name: 'Thriller' },{ id: 10752, name: 'War' },{ id: 37, name: 'Western' },{ name: 'Trending' },{ name: 'Top Rated' }];

const useLocalCompare = (a, b) => 
  !(a.localeCompare(b, false, { sensitivity: "base" }));

const filterByName = (data, targetName) => 
  data.filter(({ name }) => useLocalCompare(name, targetName));
  
console.log(filterByName(data, 'Top Rated'));
console.log(filterByName(data, 'top ráted'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```